# variables alteration in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, variables

i got a ridiculous problem.

i have a class within inside an array member.i have a get method and a set method for the array.

the problem is that i call the set(to update) method to change the variables within the array and i see with the debugger that the variables do actually update.then when i call immediately the get method just after the set method i found the variables of the array been changed back to their ancient values.
here is the code approximately :

```
object.updatFunction();//sort of set method
//nothing in between
Type variable=object.getFunction();
```

added code:

```
void Cube::updtCornersNextToCentr()
{
int iHalfSide=m_SideSize/2;
int centerX(m_Center.x()),centerY(m_Center.y()),centerZ(m_Center.z());

m_CubeCornerVertices[0].setX(centerX-iHalfSide);
m_CubeCornerVertices[0].setY(centerY+iHalfSide);
m_CubeCornerVertices[0].setZ(centerZ-iHalfSide);

m_CubeCornerVertices[1].setX(centerX+iHalfSide);
m_CubeCornerVertices[1].setY(centerY+iHalfSide);
m_CubeCornerVertices[1].setZ(centerZ-iHalfSide);
//.......   
m_CubeCornerVertices[7].setX(centerX+iHalfSide);
m_CubeCornerVertices[7].setY(centerY-iHalfSide);
m_CubeCornerVertices[7].setZ(centerZ+iHalfSide);
}
QVector3D * Cube::getCubeCornerVertices()const
{
static QVector3D  temp[8];
for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
{
    temp[i]=m_CubeCornerVertices[i];
}
return &temp[0];
}
```

Comment: Please post code of the update and get functions. Most likely you are updating a temporary variable inside your update function.

Comment: Most likely you updated a local variable or a copy. In either case, the code you showed doesn't contain the bit causing the problem.

Comment: ok, i will post the implementation

Comment: i added the code above.is there something wrong?

Comment: why you don't just return a const& to the m_CubeCornerVertices or the adress of the m_CubeCornerVertices in a getCubeCornerVertices() non const ?

Comment: returning m_CubeCornerVertices in getCubeCornerVertices() non const will transgress encapsulation.as for returning const& i remember having avoided this for a reason.the fact is when i try a simple function-debugging like this :                                                                                      int Cube::returnSomething()
{
    return m_CubeCornerVertices[0].x();
}                                                                                                                     it gives back an undesired value: that is, the problem is not in the get function.

Comment: I'd recommend creating an MCVE ([instructions here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) so this could be solved more easily. The problem is probably somewhere else than your getter or setter.

Comment: thank you "zenith", this had come to my thought.i mean the fact that my getter and setter aren't concerned.i shall try to look elsewhere and delay the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was really ridiculous, i didn’t want to let this post ambiguous.it’s a very beginner fault and it’s all about a missing   « & » that caused me to update a copy.
Actually i did above simplify write the next code :

```
object.updatFunction();//sort of set method
//nothing in between
Type variable=object.getFunction();
```

And the more real code was something like:

```
m_WorldSpace->getCube().updtCornersNextToCentr()
//nothing in between
const QVector3D corners[8]=m_WorldSpace->getCube().getCubeCornerVertices();
```

all the problem was in the getCube() function which instead of being something like this :

```
Cube& WorldSpace::getCube()//here is the missing "&"
{
return m_Cube;
}
```

I wrote this

```
Cube WorldSpace::getCube()//this caused to get and update just a temporary copy
{
return m_Cube;
}
```

someone can say that i got multiple levels of getters which blinded me.
thank you.